# Array element at index always returns 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to change a simple value in an array at a specific position, but even if the value within the array is not 0, when trying to change the value, this becomes 0.
This happens in a simple loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int stat = child[i];   // stat becomes 0 even if child[i] is != 0
    // some calculation on stat here
}
```

I've used VS17 debugger to try to understand what it is exactly happening, but I still don't know why this happens. In my application I've already set other variables to elements in array, but this is the first time I've seen anything like that. 
According to the debugger, `stat = 0`, even if `child[i] != 0`:

[image]

This happens thoughout all the loop. I'm sure that it is something that I'm missing, but I really can't get what it is.

Comment: you need to execute the line of code. You stopped right before it updated the value of `stat` you need to go to the next line to see the value afterwards.

Comment: Read my reply to the other answer, please

Comment: Add Debug.Log(string.Format("stat is {0}", stat));  I bet it's not zero.  When the variable assignment is the only statement in the loop it's hard to say what the scope is.  At what point in the loop is `stat` in scope and has its value?  There is *no statement* that exists in this state.  By adding a Debog.Log statement, you introduce a statement that *does* have these properties (stat is in scope post assignment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the debugger is stopped on the line like that, it hasn't executed that line of code yet.  Since the line hasn't been executed, `stat` hasn't been assigned the value of `child[i]` and the debugger just shows the default value for an integer (0).  It's working just fine.  If you want to see the value change, go to the next statement.

Comment: I know that, but even after the execution of the code "stat" is still 0. I know this because the returned child has 0 at indexes 0-3. Oherwise I would't had any problems...

Comment: Remember that each time you go around the loop, the variable `stat` get's reinitialized again.  So if you don't stop and check the value after that line but before the loop goes back again, you won't see the change.  From where your debugger has stopped, hit F10 and it should move to the close brace.  Then check the value of `stat`.  It should be what you are expecting.

Comment: @Koosshh56 You should probably change the screenshot you provided then, because it's the most obvious problem as is -- that you haven't yet executed the line of code.  Also, that the code you depict is not "changing" `child` it is only "reading" from it.  Furthermore, you haven't shown how you observe that the values of the array that you pass in do not get modified.  (e.g. was a copy of the array passed to checkValidityStats?)